# Нужно получить список Wi-Fi сигналов(Android)

Tags: java, android

Можно ли постоянно в фоновом режиме получать список точек Wi-Fi и сравнивать названия с теми которые нужны? И как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Тут [Доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan) а здесь [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android/18741306)

Comment: Можно, из подводных камней - на устройстве должна быть разрешена геолокация (на последних Андроидах).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan сделал, но приходится постоянно сканировать. Можно ли это реализовать так, чтобы приложение всегда видела все доступные сети? Просто пока я вижу вариант, сканить каждые 5-10 с и выводить список, но мне кажется, что так лучше не делать.